# How put points in an 2D coordinate system radomly?

Tags: c++

> ```
> i want this code can show:
>  1 2 3 ....      10
> 1 *               *
> 2    @
> .
> . *
>
> 10 *
> ```

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
int coordinates[1][10] = { 1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    cout << " " << coordinates[k][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < 1; r++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < 10; s++) {
            cout << coordinates[r][s] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

I want put sign@ in position(3,2), LIKE THE ABOVE 
and also put some points(*) into coordinate system randomly, and the points cannot be put them at 8 immediate neighbors of  @position(3,2)

Comment: Start by making a function that returns some random coordinates. Then a function that puts a character at a set of coordinates.

Comment: BTW, I did not downvote however I suspect your question got downvoted because at StackOverflow you need to actually attempt the problem and show that in your code. We generally don't just write code for you if there is no attempt to solve the problem in the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to make a 2d array of characters:

```
char board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS] = {0};
```

A better improvement is to use an extra column for the newline character:

```
char board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS + 1] = {0};
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < MAX_ROWS; ++i)
{
    board[i][MAX_COLUMNS] = '\n';
}
```

The extra column allows you to print the board with one statement:

```
std::cout << board << "\n";
```

If you want *fancies*, you can set up the output attributes before printing:

```
std::cout.width(3); // each cell is 3 wide
std::cout.fill(' '); // Pad each cell with spaces.
std::cout << board << "\n";
```

You can also add an extra column for displaying the row numbers and an extra row for display column numbers.

**Edit 1: Setting a point**
Setting a point is simple:

```
board[row][column] = '*';  // Set a point.
board[x][y] = ' '; // Erase a point.
```

Since the board is of type `char`, you can use different characters as points, such as `'-', '+', 'M'`, etc.